# Generating entity classes without using prompt command yo jhipster:entity

Tags: jhipster

Is it possible to generate entity from files and not from command `yo jhipster:entity` ?

In fact, when you are upgrading project, all classes were modified by this command line `yo jhipster`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In new version of jhipster, when you generate entity with command prompt, there will be an entityName.json file create in .jhipster directory of project. Then you can modify this file and generate entity related files with `yo jhipster:entity entityName`.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment.
This is often asked, and it is do-able. Our only concern is that some questions have validation, or depend on external things (the presence of a file, for example), so this wouldn't be as powerful as the command line tool.
But given the pace of the project, you should expect this pretty soon.